# Как убрать вопрос "сохранить изменения или нет" после изменения файла?

Tags: delphi, excel

Как сделать так что бы после того как я ввёл изменения в экселевский файл программа не спрашивала "сохранить изменения или нет". Мне нужно чтобы изменения НЕ сохранялись

Comment: При чем здесь дельфи? Вы открываете документ эксель через дельфи при помощи OLE ?

Comment: Можно вообще выключить подобные сообщения:  

    ExcelOLE.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Answer (score 2):

```
exelapp.workbooks[1].Close(SaveChanges:=False);
```